# how to animate drop a element in paper using jointjs

Tags: jquery, jointjs

I want to animate an object in a graph when we drop the element.

```
new joint.dia.Graph().on({

    'add': function(cell, collection, opt) {

        // Here I want to animate the element while dropped.
    }

});
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add the following code to animate the element.

```
cell.transition('position/y',250, { 
            duration: 200,
            timingFunction: function(t) { return t*t; },
            valueFunction: function(a, b) { 
                return function(t) { return a + (b - a) * t }}
});
```